# Execute query based on number of rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I'm not too great with MySQL, but I'm trying to create a trigger so that whenever a row is inserted, if the total count of rows in the table is bigger than 10 a certain row is deleted.

What I'm looking for, without the trigger syntax, is something like this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) > 10 THEN
//do some stuff
END IF;
```

However that does not seem to be acceptable syntax. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER &&

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON table_name FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE x INT;
SET x = (SELECT count(*) FROM table_name); 

IF x > 10 THEN

    DELETE FROM table_name where condition;

END IF;

END&&

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Gives me the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''before_insert_wall' BEFORE INSERT ON 'wall' FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE x ' at line 1

Comment: Do not use quote on trigger name. By the way, for more details, please  check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: It seems to not like the DECLARE x INT; part, but I can't find anything on why it's wrong.

Comment: Because by default, the mysql treat `;` as end delimiter

Answer (score -1):

```
select count(1) into @cnt from table;
if (@cnt > 10) then
   // do some stuff
end if;
```

instead of `@cnt` you can used declared variable